# Missing solution after solving system of equations.

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

I have been learning linear algebra from book ,,Mathematics for Machine Learning", all seems pretty clear and straight-forward for now, but I have encountered one problem. There was a system of equastions to solve, and i think that there is one solution missing. [Here are the solutions from the text book.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqFF4.png)
I noticed that matrix [0,-1,-1,2,1]^T also solves this equation, and it is not in solutions (and they clearly stated that general solution contains set of **all** possible solutions).

[The solution with matrix they gave in solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIoU7.png)

[The solution I think also fits this system of equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh5aF.png)

I guess that there wouldn't be a mistake like this in a textbook, so maybe I am missing something after all, could someone help me with this one, and write why I am right/wrong?

Thanks for every reply!

Answer (score 1):

Your vector $\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\\-1\\2\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is a linear combination of their vectors $(-1) \begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} + (1)\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\-1\\2\\1\end{bmatrix}$, so it also solves the associated homogeneous equation, but is already included in their solution for $\lambda_1 = -1$ and $\lambda_2 = 1$.

As noted in Martin's answer, the solution to the original equation would require you to add the particular solution to the solution to the associated homogeneous equation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from the textbook is correct.

The solution you mention is a solution of the homogeneous system with the same matrix, but not of the full system. I don't know why you expect it to appear as a solution of the non-homogeneous system.